# how to transfer less than 1 eth using geth

Tags: go-ethereum

I'd like to transfer .24 eth

Using [this site](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-hex.htm) to convert .24 to hex I get 0.3D70A3D70A3D70A3D70A

Then using this command

```
eth.sendTransaction({from: "0xeadbcdf21ccd3b1d8437e6dc32509e68f638a0bc", to: "0x45c6bD2F15FDD9763dfCfAb5100829DeC5C8fbc2", value: "0x0.3D70A3D70A3D70A3D70A"})
```

I get this error:

```
Error: invalid argument 0: hex number has leading zero digits after 0x
    at web3.js:3104:20
    at web3.js:6191:15
    at web3.js:5004:36
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Is it possible to send less than 1 eth or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction

The correct unit for sending transactions is in Wei. 
You should first convert your amount by using : 
`var value = web3.toWei('0.24', 'ether');`